# $A.util.removeClass not working in some cases

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

On init of a component, I want to hide an element `lightning:buttonIcon` if some condition is satisfied(**see controller code**). In this case it is getting satisfied and I am reaching the code where element is to be hidden(**hideElement function in helper**). But the element is still visible, on the other hand, if we access the same code (hideElement function) from helper itself like:

```
this.hideElement(component, id);
```

It hides the element. What is the reason behind this?

> Markup:

```
<!-- Some code above -->

<div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-6 slds-large-size--4-of-12">
                <br/>
                <lightning:buttonIcon aura:id="addFieldButtonID" iconName="utility:new" size="large" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleFieldDone }" alternativeText="Done!"/>
                <div class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_containercircle">
                    <lightning:icon aura:id="doneFieldIcon" iconName="action:approval" size="xx-small" alternativeText="Done" class="slds-hide"/>
                </div>
                <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:clear" size="large" variant="bare" alternativeText="Remove" onclick="{! c.removeEntry }"/>
            </div>

<!-- some code below -->
```

> Controller:

```
handleInit : function(component, event, helper){

        if(component.get('v.disableEntryEdit')){
            helper.HideElement(component, 'addFieldButtonID');
        }
}
```

> Helper:

```
hideElement : function(component, id){
        var element=component.find(id);
        console.log('Element: ' , element.getLocalId()); //gives ID as :addFieldButtonID
        $A.util.removeClass(element, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(element, 'slds-hide');
        console.log('elementclass: ' , element.get('v.class')); //gives o/p : undefined
    },
```

Comment: `var divElement = component.find(id);` -- On this line, Are you sure you are getting the div enclosing the `lightning:buttonIcon` or `lightning:buttonIcon` itself?

Comment: @javanoob : I am getting the `lightning:buttonIcon` itself, i.e  : **addFieldButtonID**

Comment: Ok. Your variable naming is confusing, you named it as though you are getting div enclosing it.

Comment: agreed and changed!

Comment: @Rangya Instead of doing things in `init`, can you try it in `afterRenderer`?. Reason is that `init` is called long before DOM availability, there might be a timing issue too.

Comment: @Praveen : yes I tried it in afterRenderer and it worked! Lesson learnt that init is called after some time and got to consider renderer in this type of scenarios which I tend to ignore. Thanks, you can answer this if you want and I'll mark it

Comment: @Sarang Done. I have added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing things in `init`, try it in `afterRenderer`. Reason is that `init` is called long before DOM availability, which might cause a timing issue.

Incase of `afterRenderer` it is called only after the DOM is rendered in the view.