# $A.util.removeClass not working sometimes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, rerender

I've created rerenderer function to hide the field after component is loaded but it still doesn't work as expected.

Note: I've not added slds-hide or slds-show class in component. Just trying to hide using js when component is loaded.

```
rerender : function(component, helper) {

    this.superAfterRender();
    if(component.get("v.Value") === 'No'){
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("FieldToHide"),"slds-hide");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your exact use case but here are few things that you can do, first use the below event 'render'

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

There seems to be something wrong in this line below we do a component.find of an aura id and then do v.value not sure if this line is returning anything.

```
//if(component.find("FieldTovalidate").get("v.value") === 'No')     
if(component.get("v.Value") === 'No'){
```

you can put a try catch around this and log an error in browser console to see if this is erroring out

Comment: Thanks @RedDevil. I tried but it's not going to catch block.
I've followed solution posted here (The same use case): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158237/a-util-removeclass-not-working-in-some-cases

Comment: You need to use component.find of an aura id in render event helper function and then check the no condition. added it to my answer above.